# Is there a way I can close Thunderbird but still receive notifications in the background?

Tags: firefox, thunderbird, notification

I would like to close Thunderbird but still receive notifications in the background. I've seen other questions about this but they all reference [FireTray](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/firetray/?src=search) and it's only compatible with Thunderbird versions up to 50 and I have Thunderbird 55.0.

Are there any solutions or will I have to be alright with leaving it minimised?

Comment: What is the problem with leaving it minimised? I did not even had the idea once in 7 years, to close it but still receiving notifications?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is called "email notification", sometimes also "biff". See [gnubiff](http://gnubiff.sourceforge.net/) for instance. There are several alternatives available per apt-get.